# Como duplicar uma tabela mudando valores de string para decimal

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou aprendendo SQL e me propus a importar uma tabela .csv do banco central para aplicar os meus conhecimentos. A tabela é composta por quatro colunas:

data que foi inserido o registro | nome da moeda | valor da moeda | quantidade da moeda em circulação

**O problema é que a quantidade veio mal formatada (número com pontos e vírgula, ex: 5.000.000.000,00 para 5 bilhões).**
O arquivo .csv tem 380000 linhas, portanto é **muito inviável editar manualmente no arquivo de origem**. Já ouvi falar sobre processo ETL, imagino que talvez dê pra resolver com isso, mas como estou começando meus estudos em banco de dados não tenho conhecimento sobre isso.

**O que eu fiz? Ao importar, defini tudo como string para posteriormente alterar o tipo dos valores.**

Portanto eu tenho duas tabelas agora, a primeira tabela seria a original chamada de *circulante1* (colunas são todas string) e a segunda tabela que eu criei chamada de *circulante2* (string/string/float/double). *Eu sei que a data não é string, mas é tanto problema pra agora que queria resolver antes os valores.*

Então, a única forma que pensei de fazer isso (e pensei alguma coisa errada, pois não deu certo) foi utilizando essa confusão:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    SELECT count(*) INTO @linhas FROM circulante1;
    DECLARE @contador INT = 0;
    WHILE @contador < @linhas
    BEGIN
        SELECT data_,nome,cast(valor as float) as valor,cast(replace(replace(qntd,'.',''),',','.') AS DOUBLE) as qntd INTO 
        @data_,@nome,@valor,@qntd
        FROM circulante1
        WHERE PRIMARY = @contador + 1  -- pra ser bem sincero não sei exatamente o que fiz aqui, como não tinha nenhuma coluna auto_increment eu tentei usar isso como o index
        INSERT INTO circulante2 (data_,nome,valor,qntd) VALUES (@data_,@nome,@valor,@qntd) 
        SET @contador = @contador + 1;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @contador INT = 0; WHILE @contador < @linhas BEGIN  SELECT data_,nome,ca' at line 1

Basicamente eu não tenho a mínima ideia onde eu errei, se foi na lógica ou um problema de sintaxe. Certamente tem uma forma melhor de fazer isso também, se vocês puderem me indicar eu agradeço.

--------------- EDIT 20:47 BRT
Pessoal, o Ricardo já me respondeu, porém caso alguém saiba me dizer, o que eu fiz (apesar de ser ineficiente) está errado aonde? Gostaria de entender meu erro para tomar como aprendizado também

Comment: respondendo sua pergunta, não é possível usar comandos de estrura de laços (while, repeat) numa query, isso precisa ser declarado dentro de uma *stored procedure*, por isso seu código não deve estar funcionando

Comment: Faz sentido, Ricardo, boa pontuação. Irei estudar e tentar aplicar dentro de uma stored procedure! Muito obrigado!

Comment: isso vale para o `mysql`, outros sgbds permitem. Veja também a declaração de variáveis, diferente do `sql-server`, não é obrigatório declarar todas as variáveis iniciando por `@`. Outro ponto é que não precisaria fazer o `select` para as variáveis uma vez que não faz alterações nelas, poderia fazer o `select` direto para o `insert`, como no elemplo da minha resposta ;)
boa sorte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tem uma tabela com os dados em texto, basta fazer um `INSERT` com `SELECT` convertendo os dados:

```
INSERT INTO circulante2 
SELECT CAST(data AS DATE) as data, 
       nome,
       CAST(replace(replace(valor, '.',''), ',', '.') as DECIMAL) as valor,
       CAST(qntd AS SIGNED) as qntd
  FROM circulante1;
```

Algumas observações:

- o tipo INT é convertido com SIGNED/UNSIGNED
- números não inteiros são convertidos com CAST para DECIMAL, FLOAT e outros tipos não funcionam diretamente com CAST, leia mais aqui: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3L6ETu2mZGPX4c4R9jhWuG/0

Comment: Ricardo, excelente! Funcionou dessa forma, grato! Vou escolher sua reposta como resposta pois realmente resolveu tudo aquilo que eu tinha feito desnecessariamente, mas só um detalhe para caso alguém replique isso, é a coluna QNTD que deve ser decimal ou double, portanto ao utilizar sua solução eu mudei as variaveis as quais você sugeriu, valor para float e qntd para double pois int não suportaria (quantidade de moedas/céludas em circulação no Brasil chega na casa de bilhões!! :)

Comment: Você avaliou o uso dos tipo de dado DECIMAL ou NUMERIC?